# I can't find "instance on point" node, just "point instance"

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I'm following along with a "game-like" tutorial using version 2.93. There comes a point where the guy says use the *Instance on Points* node, but I can't find it, I can only find *Point Instance* node. Where is the *Instance on Points*?

This is what the tutorial looks like.
[image]

this is what i get in blender
[image]

Comment: The tutorial is using a newer version in which the node has been replaced.

Comment: thanks, i thought that i had the newest ver'

Comment: It's the latest stable version, 3.0 is in alpha (unstable)